# How do I manually apply an OpenGL translation matrix to a vertex?

Tags: opengl, matrix

I have a specific need to apply a stored openGL matrix to a vertex by hand. I admit a weak spot with regards to matrix math, but I have read through all the documentation I can find and I'm reasonably sure I'm doing this correctly, but I'm getting an unexpected result. What am I missing?

(Note that this may be a math question, but I suspect I'm actually misunderstanding how to apply the translation matrix, so I thought I'd try here)

In the code snippet below, #1 works fine, #2 fails...

```
float x=1;
float y=1;
float z=1;
float w=1;

float x2=0;
float y2=0;
float z2=0;
float w2=1;

// 1 THIS WORKS: 
glLoadIdentity();

// Convert from NSArray to C float
float modelMatrix[16];
for(int x=0;x<16;x++){modelMatrix[x]=[[cs.modelView objectAtIndex:x] floatValue];}

// Load the matrix the openGL way
glLoadMatrixf(modelMatrix);

// Custom function takes two coordinates and draws a box
[self drawBoxFromX:x FromY:y FromZ:z ToX:x2 ToY:y2 ToZ:z2];

//2 THIS DOES NOT WORK: Apply the matrix by hand 
glLoadIdentity();
float new_x = (x*modelMatrix[0])+(y*modelMatrix[4])+(z*modelMatrix[8])+(w*modelMatrix[12]);
float new_y = (x*modelMatrix[1])+(y*modelMatrix[5])+(z*modelMatrix[9])+(w*modelMatrix[13]);
float new_z = (x*modelMatrix[2])+(y*modelMatrix[6])+(z*modelMatrix[10])+(w*modelMatrix[14]);
float new_x2 = (x2*modelMatrix[0])+(y2*modelMatrix[4])+(z2*modelMatrix[8])+(w2*modelMatrix[12]);
float new_y2 = (x2*modelMatrix[1])+(y2*modelMatrix[5])+(z2*modelMatrix[9])+(w2*modelMatrix[13]);
float new_z2 = (x2*modelMatrix[2])+(y2*modelMatrix[6])+(z2*modelMatrix[10])+(w2*modelMatrix[14]);

// Should draw a box identical to above, but gives strange result)
[self drawBoxFromX:new_x FromY:new_y FromZ:new_z ToX:new_x2 ToY:new_y2 ToZ:new_z2];
```

---

## Update:

Based on a helpful comment below I realized I was only rotating two of the vertexes rather than all 8 of the cube. The following code works as expected, posting here for anyone who runs into a similar problem wrapping their head around 3d/opengl stuff. (Note: In case it is not obvious, this is not production code. There are many more efficient and less manual ways multiply matrices and describe cubes (see comments). The purpose of this code is simply to explicitly illustrate a behavior.)

```
struct Cube myCube;
myCube.a1.x=-1;
myCube.a1.y=-1;
myCube.a1.z=-1;

myCube.b1.x=-1;
myCube.b1.y=-1;
myCube.b1.z=1;

myCube.c1.x=1;
myCube.c1.y=-1;
myCube.c1.z=1;

myCube.d1.x=1;
myCube.d1.y=-1;
myCube.d1.z=-1;

myCube.a2.x=-1;
myCube.a2.y=1;
myCube.a2.z=-1;

myCube.b2.x=-1;
myCube.b2.y=1;
myCube.b2.z=1;

myCube.c2.x=1;
myCube.c2.y=1;
myCube.c2.z=1;

myCube.d2.x=1;
myCube.d2.y=1;
myCube.d2.z=-1;


//1 Load modelview and draw a box (this works fine)
glLoadIdentity();
float modelMatrix[16];
for(int x=0;x<16;x++){modelMatrix[x]=[[cs.modelView objectAtIndex:x] floatValue];}

glLoadMatrixf(modelMatrix);
[self drawCube:myCube];


//2 Load the matrix by hand (identical to above)
glLoadIdentity();
float w=1;

float new_Ax = (myCube.a1.x*modelMatrix[0])+(myCube.a1.y*modelMatrix[4])+(myCube.a1.z*modelMatrix[8])+(w*modelMatrix[12]);
float new_Ay = (myCube.a1.x*modelMatrix[1])+(myCube.a1.y*modelMatrix[5])+(myCube.a1.z*modelMatrix[9])+(w*modelMatrix[13]);
float new_Az = (myCube.a1.x*modelMatrix[2])+(myCube.a1.y*modelMatrix[6])+(myCube.a1.z*modelMatrix[10])+(w*modelMatrix[14]);

float new_Bx = (myCube.b1.x*modelMatrix[0])+(myCube.b1.y*modelMatrix[4])+(myCube.b1.z*modelMatrix[8])+(w*modelMatrix[12]);
float new_By = (myCube.b1.x*modelMatrix[1])+(myCube.b1.y*modelMatrix[5])+(myCube.b1.z*modelMatrix[9])+(w*modelMatrix[13]);
float new_Bz = (myCube.b1.x*modelMatrix[2])+(myCube.b1.y*modelMatrix[6])+(myCube.b1.z*modelMatrix[10])+(w*modelMatrix[14]);

float new_Cx = (myCube.c1.x*modelMatrix[0])+(myCube.c1.y*modelMatrix[4])+(myCube.c1.z*modelMatrix[8])+(w*modelMatrix[12]);
float new_Cy = (myCube.c1.x*modelMatrix[1])+(myCube.c1.y*modelMatrix[5])+(myCube.c1.z*modelMatrix[9])+(w*modelMatrix[13]);
float new_Cz = (myCube.c1.x*modelMatrix[2])+(myCube.c1.y*modelMatrix[6])+(myCube.c1.z*modelMatrix[10])+(w*modelMatrix[14]);

float new_Dx = (myCube.d1.x*modelMatrix[0])+(myCube.d1.y*modelMatrix[4])+(myCube.d1.z*modelMatrix[8])+(w*modelMatrix[12]);
float new_Dy = (myCube.d1.x*modelMatrix[1])+(myCube.d1.y*modelMatrix[5])+(myCube.d1.z*modelMatrix[9])+(w*modelMatrix[13]);
float new_Dz = (myCube.d1.x*modelMatrix[2])+(myCube.d1.y*modelMatrix[6])+(myCube.d1.z*modelMatrix[10])+(w*modelMatrix[14]);

float new_A2x = (myCube.a2.x*modelMatrix[0])+(myCube.a2.y*modelMatrix[4])+(myCube.a2.z*modelMatrix[8])+(w*modelMatrix[12]);
float new_A2y = (myCube.a2.x*modelMatrix[1])+(myCube.a2.y*modelMatrix[5])+(myCube.a2.z*modelMatrix[9])+(w*modelMatrix[13]);
float new_A2z = (myCube.a2.x*modelMatrix[2])+(myCube.a2.y*modelMatrix[6])+(myCube.a2.z*modelMatrix[10])+(w*modelMatrix[14]);

float new_B2x = (myCube.b2.x*modelMatrix[0])+(myCube.b2.y*modelMatrix[4])+(myCube.b2.z*modelMatrix[8])+(w*modelMatrix[12]);
float new_B2y = (myCube.b2.x*modelMatrix[1])+(myCube.b2.y*modelMatrix[5])+(myCube.b2.z*modelMatrix[9])+(w*modelMatrix[13]);
float new_B2z = (myCube.b2.x*modelMatrix[2])+(myCube.b2.y*modelMatrix[6])+(myCube.b2.z*modelMatrix[10])+(w*modelMatrix[14]);

float new_C2x = (myCube.c2.x*modelMatrix[0])+(myCube.c2.y*modelMatrix[4])+(myCube.c2.z*modelMatrix[8])+(w*modelMatrix[12]);
float new_C2y = (myCube.c2.x*modelMatrix[1])+(myCube.c2.y*modelMatrix[5])+(myCube.c2.z*modelMatrix[9])+(w*modelMatrix[13]);
float new_C2z = (myCube.c2.x*modelMatrix[2])+(myCube.c2.y*modelMatrix[6])+(myCube.c2.z*modelMatrix[10])+(w*modelMatrix[14]);

float new_D2x = (myCube.d2.x*modelMatrix[0])+(myCube.d2.y*modelMatrix[4])+(myCube.d2.z*modelMatrix[8])+(w*modelMatrix[12]);
float new_D2y = (myCube.d2.x*modelMatrix[1])+(myCube.d2.y*modelMatrix[5])+(myCube.d2.z*modelMatrix[9])+(w*modelMatrix[13]);
float new_D2z = (myCube.d2.x*modelMatrix[2])+(myCube.d2.y*modelMatrix[6])+(myCube.d2.z*modelMatrix[10])+(w*modelMatrix[14]);



myCube.a1.x=new_Ax;
myCube.a1.y=new_Ay;
myCube.a1.z=new_Az;

myCube.b1.x=new_Bx;
myCube.b1.y=new_By;
myCube.b1.z=new_Bz;

myCube.c1.x=new_Cx;
myCube.c1.y=new_Cy;
myCube.c1.z=new_Cz;

myCube.d1.x=new_Dx;
myCube.d1.y=new_Dy;
myCube.d1.z=new_Dz;

myCube.a2.x=new_A2x;
myCube.a2.y=new_A2y;
myCube.a2.z=new_A2z;

myCube.b2.x=new_B2x;
myCube.b2.y=new_B2y;
myCube.b2.z=new_B2z;

myCube.c2.x=new_C2x;
myCube.c2.y=new_C2y;
myCube.c2.z=new_C2z;

myCube.d2.x=new_D2x;
myCube.d2.y=new_D2y;
myCube.d2.z=new_D2z;



[self drawCube:myCube];
```

Comment: What is the matrix mode while doing all this? Normally, you need to call `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` or `glMatrixMode(GL_PERSPECTIVE)` before setting any matrices. Once you've done that, you don't need to multiply the vertices by the matrix - OpenGL will do it for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW). I do understand the normal way to use OpenGL, but I have a specific need to keep track of the transformations by hand for another processing task later... (In short, I am rendering arbitrarily positioned pointclouds and intend to create a single large cloud, which requires me to be able to position them and then "go back" to get each points' global coordinate. Since it's not actually possible or practical to query each point for its "real" coordinate (I don't think), I'm tracking the transformations instead. Hope that makes sense...)

Comment: Drawing a rotated box is not the same as rotating box corners and then drawing an axis-parallel box.

Comment: Why reinvent when wheel when you can for example use GLM?

Comment: You lack the transform into the window space AFAIK. Review the GL specs. Where's the perspective divide?

Comment: I will probably use GLM, but I'm trying to verify that I understand what's going on by doing it by hand first, and I'm clearly missing something. Thanks n.m./user1095108 for the clues...

Comment: @n.m., Could you post that as an answer? That was exactly my problem, I'm doing all the math correctly but rotating only two of the vertexes is (when pointed out) obviously insufficient. Transform all 8 and it all works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @andrew: As an aside, if you want to understand what's going under the hood and try out everything for learning, I'd suggest you to try OpenGL 3.3+ shader-based programming since in modern OpenGL matrices are not maintained by OpenGL hence you can write your own matrix class and try out things from scratch. Also pre OpenGL 3.3 is deprecated now.

Comment: @legends2k Thank you... at the moment OpenGL is a necessary evil for a much larger project I'm working on OSX, which has somewhat limited 3.3 support. I'm actually using shaders/GLSL to render the pointclouds in my ap but your point is well taken! As someone new to developing 3D graphics and with a somewhat wobbly grasp on maths, I find the concepts a challenge and figuring out what's "really" happening extremely difficult. Part of this is that OpenGl is complex, but also the "way to do it" seems to change fundamentally with each version, which may or not actually work given the environment…

Comment: @legends2k …I'm not complaining, but piecing together a decent education from outdated posts makes me speak OpenGl the way I speak French (embarrassing grammatical disaster that still manages to help me acquire beer). Also makes it difficult to tell if the problems I'm encountering are because I don't get OpenGL, the math or the syntax (or all three). RTFM rarely helps because the same concepts are expressed quite differently version to version. I would benefit from a sitdown with an actual graphics dev, but until then brute force experiments like the above and asking the internet ;)

Comment: @andrew: Got it :) I guess when you understand the math behing CG both OpenGL (or Direct3D) and respective syntax of APIs are more of an implementation detail and it'll fall in place when you've got your math right. That said I'm still learning and these http://amzn.com/0123742978 http://amzn.com/1568817231 are helping me a lot in the dark. When you read from the web, the exact problem you'd mentioned of different authors using different notation, handedness, etc. comes up to confuse an already confused reader; OTOH when you follow a book this is completely avoided. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @legends2k Very helpful... I just ordered both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing a rotated box is not the same as rotating two of the box corners and then drawing an axis-parallel box. The simplest way to draw a transformed 3D box is to transform all 8 vertices.